# json deserialization -- StackOverflowException

Tags: json, jackson

I'm just trying to parse a json input, which is an implementation of AbstractList, containing custom objects.  But, for some reason, when it hits the deserializer for CustomerDealerRecord, it never gets past the first node, and then ends up throwing a StackOverflowException.  I've been pounding at this for like 4 hours, and I've done numerous different Google searches to no avail.  So, my last ditch effort is coming here.  Any light you all can shed on this will be much appreciated.  Thank you.  The code is below.

```
public class PhoneDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Phone>{

public PhoneDeserializer() {
    super(Phone.class);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public Phone deserialize(JsonParser jp,
        DeserializationContext ctx) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) jp.getCodec();
    return  mapper.readValue(jp, Phone.class);
}

}
```

--

```
public class CustomerDealerRecordDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<CustomerDealerRecord>{

public CustomerDealerRecordDeserializer() {
    super(CustomerDealerRecord.class);
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public CustomerDealerRecord deserialize(JsonParser jp,
        DeserializationContext ctx) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) jp.getCodec();
    return mapper.readValue(jp, CustomerDealerRecord.class);
}

}
```

-- This is the Custom List

```
public class CustomerDealerRecordList extends AbstractList<CustomerDealerRecord> {
private List<CustomerDealerRecord> records = new ArrayList<CustomerDealerRecord>();
@Override
public CustomerDealerRecord get(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return records.get(index);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return records.size();
}

public boolean add(CustomerDealerRecord cdr){
    return records.add(cdr);
}

}
```

-- This is the Controller method

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public String getCustomerDealerReportAsExcel(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp){
    VelocityContext vc = new VelocityContext();
    vc.put("response", resp);

    // Jackson stuff
    CustomerDealerRecordDeserializer deser = new CustomerDealerRecordDeserializer();
    PhoneDeserializer phoneDeser = new PhoneDeserializer();

    // We have to create a module for the alias'ed class
    SimpleModule cdrModule = new SimpleModule("CustomerDealerRecord", new Version(1,0,0,null));
    SimpleModule phoneModule = new SimpleModule("Phone", new Version(1,0,0,null));

    // Add the deserializer to the module
    cdrModule.addDeserializer(CustomerDealerRecord.class, deser);
    phoneModule.addDeserializer(Phone.class, phoneDeser);

    // Now, create our mapper and then register the module to it.
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(cdrModule);
    mapper.registerModule(phoneModule);

    CustomerDealerRecordList list = null;

    try {
        JsonParser jp = mapper.getJsonFactory().createJsonParser(req.getParameter("json"));
        list = mapper.readValue(jp, CustomerDealerRecordList.class);
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return format(req, vc, "reports/customer_dealer_report_excel");
}
```

-- This is the Phone Model object

```
public class Phone {

    public Phone(String areaCode, String phone){
        this.areaCode = areaCode;
        this.phoneNumber = phone;
    }
    private String areaCode;
    private String phoneNumber;
    public String getAreaCode() {
        return areaCode;
    }
    public void setAreaCode(String areaCode) {
        this.areaCode = areaCode;
    }
    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }
    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

-- This is the CustomerDealerRecord Model object

```
public class CustomerDealerRecord {
    private String fleetName;
    private String fleetNumber;
    private String dealerName;
    private String dealerNumber;
    private String territoryName;
    private String territoryNumber;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private Date downTime;
    private String failureDescription;
    private String tireManufacturer;
    private String tireSize;
    private String tireType;
    private String tirePosition;
    private String category;
    private String callerName;
    private Phone callerPhone;
    private String caseNumber;
    private Date caseCloseDate;
    private String poNumber;
    private String truckNumber;
    private String trailerNumber;
    private String tractorNumber;
    private String serviceDetailStatus;
    private String refusalReason;

    public String getFleetName() {
        return fleetName;
    }

    public void setFleetName(String fleetName) {
        this.fleetName = fleetName;
    }

    public String getFleetNumber() {
        return fleetNumber;
    }

    public void setFleetNumber(String fleetNumber) {
        this.fleetNumber = fleetNumber;
    }

    public String getDealerName() {
        return dealerName;
    }

    public void setDealerName(String dealerName) {
        this.dealerName = dealerName;
    }

    public String getDealerNumber() {
        return dealerNumber;
    }

    public void setDealerNumber(String dealerNumber) {
        this.dealerNumber = dealerNumber;
    }

    public String getTerritoryName() {
        return territoryName;
    }

    public void setTerritoryName(String territoryName) {
        this.territoryName = territoryName;
    }

    public String getTerritoryNumber() {
        return territoryNumber;
    }

    public void setTerritoryNumber(String territoryNumber) {
        this.territoryNumber = territoryNumber;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public Date getDownTime() {
        return downTime;
    }

    public void setDownTime(Date downTime) {
        this.downTime = downTime;
    }

    public String getFailureDescription() {
        return failureDescription;
    }

    public void setFailureDescription(String failureDescription) {
        this.failureDescription = failureDescription;
    }

    public String getTireManufacturer() {
        return tireManufacturer;
    }

    public void setTireManufacturer(String tireManufacturer) {
        this.tireManufacturer = tireManufacturer;
    }

    public String getTireSize() {
        return tireSize;
    }

    public void setTireSize(String tireSize) {
        this.tireSize = tireSize;
    }

    public String getTireType() {
        return tireType;
    }

    public void setTireType(String tireType) {
        this.tireType = tireType;
    }

    public String getTirePosition() {
        return tirePosition;
    }

    public void setTirePosition(String tirePosition) {
        this.tirePosition = tirePosition;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getCallerName() {
        return callerName;
    }

    public void setCallerName(String callerName) {
        this.callerName = callerName;
    }

    public Phone getCallerPhone() {
        return callerPhone;
    }

    public void setCallerPhone(Phone callerPhone) {
        this.callerPhone = callerPhone;
    }

    public String getCaseNumber() {
        return caseNumber;
    }

    public void setCaseNumber(String caseNumber) {
        this.caseNumber = caseNumber;
    }

    public Date getCaseCloseDate() {
        return caseCloseDate;
    }

    public void setCaseCloseDate(Date caseCloseDate) {
        this.caseCloseDate = caseCloseDate;
    }

    public String getPoNumber() {
        return poNumber;
    }

    public void setPoNumber(String poNumber) {
        this.poNumber = poNumber;
    }

    public String getTruckNumber() {
        return truckNumber;
    }

    public void setTruckNumber(String truckNumber) {
        this.truckNumber = truckNumber;
    }

    public String getTrailerNumber() {
        return trailerNumber;
    }

    public void setTrailerNumber(String trailerNumber) {
        this.trailerNumber = trailerNumber;
    }

    public String getTractorNumber() {
        return tractorNumber;
    }

    public void setTractorNumber(String tractorNumber) {
        this.tractorNumber = tractorNumber;
    }

    public String getServiceDetailStatus() {
        return serviceDetailStatus;
    }

    public void setServiceDetailStatus(String serviceDetailStatus) {
        this.serviceDetailStatus = serviceDetailStatus;
    }

    public String getRefusalReason() {
        return refusalReason;
    }

    public void setRefusalReason(String refusalReason) {
        this.refusalReason = refusalReason;
    }

}
```

-- Sample JSON

```
[
{
"fleetName":"sycamore specialzed carriers",
"fleetNumber":"CF00002760",
"dealerName":null,
"dealerNumber":null,
"territoryName":null,
"territoryNumber":null,
"city":null,
"state":null,
"downTime":"3000-01-01",
"failureDescription":null,
"tireManufacturer":"Continental Tire",
"tireSize":"10.00R15",
"tireType":"DRIVE",
"tirePosition":"LFO",
"category":"Dealer Location Information",
"callerName":"ANN RENNER",
"callerPhone":{
"areaCode":null,
"phoneNumber":null
},
"caseNumber":"189354",
"caseCloseDate":null,
"poNumber":null,
"truckNumber":null,
"trailerNumber":null,
"tractorNumber":null,
"serviceDetailStatus":"CAN",
"refusalReason":"Response time"
},
{
"fleetName":"sycamore specialzed carriers",
"fleetNumber":"CF00002760",
"dealerName":null,
"dealerNumber":null,
"territoryName":null,
"territoryNumber":null,
"city":null,
"state":null,
"downTime":"3000-01-01",
"failureDescription":null,
"tireManufacturer":null,
"tireSize":null,
"tireType":null,
"tirePosition":null,
"category":"Dealer Location Information",
"callerName":"ANN RENNER",
"callerPhone":{
"areaCode":null,
"phoneNumber":null
},
"caseNumber":"189354",
"caseCloseDate":null,
"poNumber":null,
"truckNumber":null,
"trailerNumber":null,
"tractorNumber":null,
"serviceDetailStatus":"ACT",
"refusalReason":null
},
{
"fleetName":"sycamore specialzed carriers",
"fleetNumber":"CF00002760",
"dealerName":null,
"dealerNumber":null,
"territoryName":null,
"territoryNumber":null,
"city":null,
"state":null,
"downTime":"3000-01-01",
"failureDescription":null,
"tireManufacturer":"Continental Tire",
"tireSize":"295/75R22.5",
"tireType":"BIAS",
"tirePosition":"LMI",
"category":"Service Call",
"callerName":" ",
"callerPhone":{
"areaCode":null,
"phoneNumber":null
},
"caseNumber":"189240",
"caseCloseDate":null,
"poNumber":null,
"truckNumber":null,
"trailerNumber":null,
"tractorNumber":null,
"serviceDetailStatus":"CAN",
"refusalReason":"Other"
},
{
"fleetName":"sycamore specialzed carriers",
"fleetNumber":"CF00002760",
"dealerName":null,
"dealerNumber":null,
"territoryName":null,
"territoryNumber":null,
"city":null,
"state":null,
"downTime":"3000-01-01",
"failureDescription":null,
"tireManufacturer":"Continental Tire",
"tireSize":"295/75R22.5",
"tireType":"DRIVE",
"tirePosition":"LMI",
"category":"Service Call",
"callerName":" ",
"callerPhone":{
"areaCode":null,
"phoneNumber":null
},
"caseNumber":"189240",
"caseCloseDate":null,
"poNumber":null,
"truckNumber":null,
"trailerNumber":null,
"tractorNumber":null,
"serviceDetailStatus":"ACT",
"refusalReason":null
},
{
"fleetName":"TEST CUSTOMER",
"fleetNumber":"123ee22a",
"dealerName":null,
"dealerNumber":null,
"territoryName":null,
"territoryNumber":null,
"city":null,
"state":null,
"downTime":"3000-01-01",
"failureDescription":null,
"tireManufacturer":null,
"tireSize":null,
"tireType":null,
"tirePosition":null,
"category":"Service Call",
"callerName":"JASON MA",
"callerPhone":{
"areaCode":"123",
"phoneNumber":"222"
},
"caseNumber":"189328",
"caseCloseDate":"2012-01-03",
"poNumber":null,
"truckNumber":null,
"trailerNumber":null,
"tractorNumber":null,
"serviceDetailStatus":"ACT",
"refusalReason":"Other"
},
{
"fleetName":"TEST CUSTOMER",
"fleetNumber":"123ee22a",
"dealerName":null,
"dealerNumber":null,
"territoryName":null,
"territoryNumber":null,
"city":"ST LOUIS",
"state":"MO",
"downTime":"3000-01-01",
"failureDescription":"REPAIR IF POSSIBLE",
"tireManufacturer":"Continental Tire",
"tireSize":"11R22.5",
"tireType":"RADIAL",
"tirePosition":"LRI",
"category":"Service Call",
"callerName":"BJ TEST",
"callerPhone":{
"areaCode":"314",
"phoneNumber":"592-3129"
},
"caseNumber":"189341",
"caseCloseDate":"2012-06-19",
"poNumber":null,
"truckNumber":null,
"trailerNumber":"34",
"tractorNumber":"12",
"serviceDetailStatus":"CAN",
"refusalReason":"Product not available"
},
{
"fleetName":"TEST CUSTOMER",
"fleetNumber":"123ee22a",
"dealerName":null,
"dealerNumber":null,
"territoryName":null,
"territoryNumber":null,
"city":"ST LOUIS",
"state":"MO",
"downTime":"3000-01-01",
"failureDescription":"REPAIR IF POSSIBLE",
"tireManufacturer":"Continental Tire",
"tireSize":"11R22.5",
"tireType":"RADIAL",
"tirePosition":"LRI",
"category":"Service Call",
"callerName":"BJ TEST",
"callerPhone":{
"areaCode":"314",
"phoneNumber":"592-3129"
},
"caseNumber":"189341",
"caseCloseDate":"2012-06-19",
"poNumber":null,
"truckNumber":null,
"trailerNumber":"34",
"tractorNumber":"12",
"serviceDetailStatus":"ACT",
"refusalReason":null
}
]
```

Comment: Can you add a sample JSON string you are trying to parse to the question?

Comment: Looks like your phone deserializer calls your phone deserializer.

Comment: Where are you seeing that?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  Lol.  I gave a ton of information, and the thing had no suitable answers.  Whatever.  Haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, initially I didn't use the deserializer, and as @pgelinas said, it wasn't needed.  That was where I got after playing around with things. It didn't work. The underlying problem was that I had to go back to using mapper.convertValue and give the Phone class a public no arg constructor. Basically, I'm an idiot and was just over-analyzing the simple.

Comment: You could also keep your current constructor and annotate the parameters with `@JsonProperty`. You'd need to specify the property name in the annotation. Jackson will properly resolve the constructor and use it instead of using the setters. Added bonus: the class can be made immutable since you don't need the setters for Jackson anymore ;)

Answer (score 1):

As @bmargulies commented, the PhoneDeserializer calls (indirectly) the PhoneDeserializer. The line `mapper.readValue(jp, Phone.class);` will let Jackson resolve the deserializer for the Phone class, which happens to be PhoneDeserializer. You don't need the Phonedeserializer class at all, Jackson will handle your phone class properly.

Comment: Yeah, initially I didn't use the deserializer.  It didn't work.  The underlying problem was that I had to go back to using convertValue and give the Phone class a public no arg constructor.  Basically, I'm an idiot and was just over-analyzing the simple.